# IOS Upload Images To S3 With Pre Signed URLs From Back-End

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload images from an IOS App with a Rails Back-end server to Amazon s3.

Is this the flow of the upload?

-> IOS Client

1. -> Request Back-End for Pre Signed URL
2. -> Back-End makes a request to S3 for pre-signed URL
3. -> Back-End sends pre-signed URL to IOS
4. -> IOS client uploads to S3 with pre-signed URL

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I am stuck with the same problem. My image is getting corrupted in between, I guess. I am not able to see the image when I get the downloadable link.