# Do I need to include aws sdk in ios xcode project if I want to upload with presigned url?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, swift2

As I don't want to include my AWS credentials in iOS client, I am generating presigned URL in my service and use the url in iOS client to upload images to S3. This setup is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188958/ios-upload-images-to-s3-with-pre-signed-urls-from-back-end). In this case, do I need to include  aws sdk in my ios xcode project or I can achieve everything through NSURLSession?

When I try this only with NSURLSession, I am getting connection timeout error and most of the answers related to this problem revolve around parameters of AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest which is part of aws SDK, which I am not using so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we don't need aws SDK. The problem is that when I try the same request via CURL, I am getting access denied error but somehow NSError description states this as "Connection Timeout". Once I fixed permission issues in IAM, it started working fine.